# Why am i getting always undefined checkbox value?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I am creating some checkboxes in a div using these line of code:

```
 for(j=0;j<allActivities.length;j++){
   $('#activity_checkboxlist').append('<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"'+j+' value="'+allActivities[j].activitynumber+'"/>'+allActivities[j].activityname+'<br>');
 }
```

Where `activity_checkboxlist` is a div. Now i am checking if a check box is checked then put its value in an array. I am doing that using this code:

```
var selectedareas = new Array();

for (i = 0; i < allActivities.length; i++) {

    var chkval = $('#checkbox' + i + ':checked').val();
    alert(chkval);
    if (chkval !== undefined) {
        selectedareas.push(chkval);
    }
}
```

That alert always shows that chkval's value is undefined. even i check those checkboxes. Is there any wrong with my code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post HTML... and also the JS that defines allActivities

Comment: BTW, not related to your question but it would be easier for you to fetch the checked values by doing `$('#activity_checkboxlist :checkbox:checked').each(function(){});`.

Comment: but then how i will add value of that specific checkbox in selectedareas array?

Comment: You can still use the codes inside the for-loop. Only difference is that you'll use `var chkval = $(this).val()` instead to get the checkbox's value, or `selectedareas.push($(this).val());`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked you HTML after generatinng? You have put `"` in the worong part of the line.

With:

```
$('#activity_checkboxlist').append('<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"'+j+' value="'+allActivities[j].activitynumber+'"/>'+allActivities[j].activityname+'<br>');
```

You have IDs like `id="checkbox"1 value=...`. Move your closing `"` to the second part to generate the right IDs:

```
$('#activity_checkboxlist').append('<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox'+j+'" value="'+allActivities[j].activitynumber+'"/>'+allActivities[j].activityname+'<br>');
```

Comment: @JohnP Thanks for the english lesson :)